# Seeking sample code for Translucent ui.Panels

Tags: google-earth-engine

I just saw this wonderful [app](https://showcase.earthengine.app/view/jrc-global-surface-water-animation#center=%7B%22type%22%3A%22Point%22%2C%22coordinates%22%3A%5B-74.60996349676783%2C9.177951367275712%5D%7D;zoom=12;aoi=%7B%22type%22%3A%22Polygon%22%2C%22coordinates%22%3A%5B%5B%5B-74.42438711053532%2C9.247256668172326%5D%2C%5B-74.42438711053532%2C9.24327502945795%5D%2C%5B-74.42095388299626%2C9.24327502945795%5D%2C%5B-74.42095388299626%2C9.247256668172326%5D%5D%5D%2C%22geodesic%22%3Afalse%2C%22evenOdd%22%3Atrue%7D;render=Cumulative%20history;fps=20;fade=0.18;) posted on Twitter and I would like to learn how to create a panel like the one below. Note the background is a little translucent and the gray area is contained inside of a black frame.

Does anybody have a sample code for me to look at?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a CSS `rgba` function as the `backgroundColor` style property on `ui.Panel` and `ee.Label` elements that allows you to set transparency (alpha):

```
var transparentPanel =  ui.Panel({
  style: {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', height: '200px', width: '200px'}
});
Map.add(panel);
```

Here is the code that makes the notes panel for the app you link to:

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2020 Google LLC.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 * 
 * @description
 * Earth Engine App collapsible note code snippet from:
 *   https://showcase.earthengine.app/view/jrc-global-surface-water-animation
 */

// Function to handle showing and hiding the notes panel.
var notesShow = false;
function notesButtonHandler() {
  if(notesShow){
    notesShow = false;
    notesPanel.style().set('shown', false);
    notesPanel.style().set('width', '83px');
    notesButton.setLabel('See notes');
  } else {
    notesShow = true;
    notesPanel.style().set('shown', true);
    notesPanel.style().set('width', '290px');
    notesButton.setLabel('Hide notes');
  }
}

// Note style.
var noteStyle = {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)', fontSize: '11px', fontWeight: '500', margin: '8px 8px 1px 8px'};

// Show/hide note button.
var notesButton = ui.Button({label: 'See notes', onClick: notesButtonHandler, style: {margin: '0px'}});

// Notes panel.
var notesPanel = ui.Panel({
  widgets: [
    ui.Label({value: 'This app animates 35 years of surface water changes at an annual time step.', style: noteStyle}),
    ui.Label({value: '• Use the buttons and sliders to customize the animation.', style: noteStyle}),
    ui.Label({value: '• Download the animation by right clicking on it and selecting a save option.', style: noteStyle}),
    ui.Label({value: '• URL parameters are used to save the state of the app. Copy the entire URL and send to others to share what you are seeing.', style: noteStyle}),
    ui.Label({value: '• Learn about JRC Global Surface Water dataset.', style: noteStyle, targetUrl: 'http://global-surface-water.appspot.com/'}),
    ui.Label({value: '• See data description in the Earth Engine Data Catalog.',
        style: {backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)', fontSize: '11px', fontWeight: '500', margin: '8px 8px 8px 8px'},
        targetUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/JRC_GSW1_1_YearlyHistory'})
  ],
  style: {shown: false, backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)', fontSize: '11px', fontWeight: '500'}
});

// Notes panel container.
var notesContainer = ui.Panel({widgets: [notesButton, notesPanel],
  style: {position: 'bottom-left', padding: '8px',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'}});

Map.add(notesContainer);
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6e9064e99117354bfb7165a34ba43dd1)